# Embedding IPython into QGIS console?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-python-console, ipython

I would like to use Ipython in the console to perform tasks more easily.

How can I do that?

I want to use Ipython because I prefer to program with it. I would like to have TAB-completion because the attribute of QGIS module made me crazy.

Comment: QGIS 2.0 will have auto tab completion for methods and a whole new revamped Python console.

Comment: @Nathan W I will wait for 2.0.But why don't embed Ipython by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is now an IPython plugin for QGIS developed by Alessandro Pasotti at: http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/IPyConsole/

After installing it via menu Plugins >> Mange and Install Plugins, you will find it under Plugins Toolbar or Plugin menu >> IPython QGIS Console >> Docked/Windowed